# What does this expression mean : "R.string.gcm_registered"?

Tags: android, push-notification, manifest, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to enable push notifications on my application.

I have the client sample code and now i am trying to get some of the code to implement it on my application. For those of you who have already implemented push notifications on your apps i am sure you are familiar with the class `GCMIntentService`.

So i am copying this class on my project , i configure the Manifest correctly(or i think i do) but i get errors in the file.

The errors are in expressions like `R.string."something"`

For example I get errors in :

```
R.string.gcm_registered

R.string.gcm_message

R.string.gcm_deleted

R.string.gcm_error

R.string.gcm_recoverable_error

R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm
```

The error is always that gcm cannot be resolved or is not a field.

But what exactly is this expression?! Is it a class or something?

Is it something on the Manifest that I haven't configured correctly?

Comment: Please copy all those string resources from res/value/string.xml from client sample project and put it in your project . this will resolve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It are strings, probably in the example app you're using, in /res/values/strings.xml

You put strings in there to have a localized place to put your user visible Strings in, so you have
1. One place to find all your strings, if you ever want to change and/or re-use
2. Easy access to translation by putting translations in per example /res/values-de/strings.xml

Look for that file in whatever example you're using, you'll find some XML defined strings. Copy them into your own project, in the same place.

Comment: hmm you are right. So now i dont actually want to have the string file , so i prefer to hard copy all these in my code. So i replace for example getString(R.string.gcm_deleted)  with the actual string and it works. But there are cases where i hve something like this : getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);   Here what is the total? And how can i hardcopy my string?

Comment: You do not want to hard-copy these Strings. There is nothing wrong with having a Strings.xml file, its what you're supposed to do. 
Anyway, if you really don't want to then in most places you should be able to just replace them with a hardcoded string. The getString() looks more like it is using the resource-id as ID to save data and receive data from a Bundle, Intent or something like that. Total would probably be the default value when nothing is found.

Comment: Hm ok so better to keep a file so i dont get more confused :p thanks man!

Comment: Indeed. Try to read the android developer site a bit, and read about the Resources (/res/) folder. Its a very strong tool to support multiple devices, apis, sizes and languages all with 1 app. You kinda can't escape using it, if you want to make something proper. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

this may helps you ,define all Reuired String in your `strings.xml` and `save`

```
R.string.gcm_registered

R.string.gcm_message

R.string.gcm_deleted

R.string.gcm_error
```